# ASIHTTPRequest (ASIS3ObjectRequest) - File not downloaded

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

I'm having an issue with accessing my downloaded file. I can see that 
my downloaded data is coming through using the didReceiveData delegate 
method but I never see the file in the directory once the request is 
finished. Also, FWIW I'm requesting a .zip file from my bucket.

```
-(void)downloadZipFile 
{ 
  ASIS3ObjectRequest *request = [ASIS3ObjectRequest 
requestWithBucket:bucket key:keyPath]; 
    [request setSecretAccessKey:secretAccessKey]; 
    [request setAccessKey:accessKey]; 
    [request setDelegate:self]; 
    [request setDownloadDestinationPath:[[self documentsDirectory] 
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.zip"]]; 
    [request startSynchronous]; 
} 

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request 
{ 
    NSError *error; 
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init]; 
    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@", [fileManager 
contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[self documentsDirectory] error:&error]); 
   //logging the contents of my documents directory shows that the file I downloaded is not there 
    [fileManager release]; 
} 

- (NSString *)documentsDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah found the problem.

First if you're writing the data to disk using downloadDestinationPath you must remove the didReceiveData delegate method from your implementation. Also make sure you set your temporaryDownloadPath.